# Jquery, What does slice return on failure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, return-value, slice

I can't find this anywhere, how do you check to see if slice is returning elements still in the list? Like `$('.class').slice(n-th,n-th);`

When n-th variables are increased throughout the index of the return class by slicing, how do you know when slice returns on an invalid index? Hope I explained that well.

Here is the example code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!($('embed').slice(p1,p2).show())){
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
    }
    ++p1;++p2;
}
```

Also, why is my event not unbinding?

Thanks for any assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply test `slice().length` to see if you got anything back, or you can test it for a specific `length`.

In your case:

```
var $mySlice = $('embed').slice(p1,p2); // <== Store slice

  // Check that slice returned 1+ elements
if( $mySlice.length ) { 

      // show them if yes
    $mySlice.show();
} else {

      // unbind if no
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
}
```

In general you want to look at:

```
$( ... ).slice( ... ).length
```

The above simply tests for 1+ elements. If you're slicing off `N` elements and you want to make sure that you get a full and complete result, simply modify to

```
if ( $mySlice.length == N ) {
```

---

jQuery's **[`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)** never returns things beyond the end of the remaining elements. It's smart enough to know when to stop.

If you give it an end point that exceeds the number of elements, it'll return the elements that exist, then it'll stop without a runtime error.

Comment: It does return an empty jQuery object, which will evaluate to true for the code he gave above, so that's not really helpful. Should be evaluating the `length` property instead.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - Of course. Thanks. Didn't quite get the question at first.

Comment: @no - Thanks - I think I actually fixed it to answer the question ;)

Comment: Thanks, answered my question and worked (checked it with firebug). :) Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Slice just returns an empty array if you pass it bad arguments.

Comment: The array is not empty. It includes the part "that makes sense". If there are 5 elements and you `jQuery(...).slice(0,999)` you will get an array of 5 elements, not an empty array.